# Undo ( ctrl + z ) functionality to bring back hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

<kbd>fiddle</kbd>  http://jsfiddle.net/Q8F5u/3/

I have **multiple divs**, each having a **delete button** on its top to delete that particular div(actually i have to hide not delete). **After the divs** have been **deleted** I want to retrieve them back **by pressing CTRL + Z.**

I have had some success in bringing them back. The Logic i have used is that i am **pushing** the deleted divs **id's to a stack** and whenever i am pressing ctrl + z, I am **popping** the last **hidden div ID from the stack** and using this id to bring back the hidden div.

Here the javascript:

```
var deletedBlocks = [];

$('.delete').on('click',function(){
   var deletedid = $(this).closest('div[id^=block]').attr('id');
    deletedBlocks.push(deletedid);
   $(this).closest('div[id^=block]').fadeOut(500); 


});

$('body').on('keydown',function(e){
    //check for ctrl + z key

    if( e.ctrlKey && e.which == 90){

        if(deletedBlocks.length > 0){

           var lastdeleted = deletedBlocks.pop();
            $('.container').children('#'+  lastdeleted).fadeIn(1000);
    }
        else{
            alert('NO further Shift to be retrieved');
        }
    }

});
```

**The problem** i am having is that in my real application there's no such unique id's for these divs. instead they all have same classes. How can i implement the same functionality without the div's having unique id's.

Comment: Just give them all a unique id. A simple counter with a prefix is sufficient, like `"div0"`, `"div1"`, `"div2"` etc.

Comment: I know i can do that. But i want know is there any other way??

Comment: Yes, you don't need to use ids. You can keep references to the DOM elements instead since you're not actually removing them from the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are just hiding the divs you can actually push the div itself to the stack instead of an ID.

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
    var deleted = $(this).closest('div[id^=block]');
    deletedBlocks.push(deleted);
    deleted.fadeOut(500); 
});

$('body').on('keydown',function(e){
    //check for ctrl + z key

    if( e.ctrlKey && e.which == 90){

        if(deletedBlocks.length > 0){

           var lastdeleted = deletedBlocks.pop();
           lastdeleted.fadeIn(1000);
        }else{

            alert('NO further Shift to be retrieved');
        }
    }

});
```

Note, I just refactored your code. Didn't test it. But you get the idea and it should work.

Comment: No problem! If it works out, please don't forget to hit the check mark on the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You might use jQuery's [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) methods.

In your line:

```
var deletedid = $(this).closest('div[id^=block]').attr('id');
```

You might retrieve the index of the deleted element:

```
var deletedIndex = $(this).closest('div[id^=block]').index();
```

Store this index in your array and use .eq() later to undelete the correct element:

```
 $('.container').closest('div[id^=block]').eq(lastdeleted).fadeIn(1000);
```